# Освобождение памяти

Tags: c++, указатели, память, vector, stl

Есть вектор указателей на объекты. Как лучше всего освобождать память: `free`, `delete` или `erase`?

Comment: Лучше приведите код, который этот вектор наполняет. Отвечающие ниже надеются на благоразумность и что Вы для создания используете new и объекты это именно объекты. Но на самом деле никто не мешает malloc'ом из своей кастомной библиотеки выделять память и наполнять её с помощью placement new.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Начнем с того, что `free` категорически противопоказан. Это C-шная функция, работающая только в паре с `malloc`.

`erase` - это функция, которая удаляет элементы из вектора. Но поскольку у вас вектор *указателей*, то автоматически память, на которую они указывают, освобождаться не будет (ведь вас это интересует?)

Так что надо перед `erase` пробежаться и освободить объекты самому. Если хотите, чтобы все делалось надежно и просто - используйте `unique_ptr` (если вектор единолично :) владеет объектами; если нет - `shared_ptr<>`).

Comment: Вместо `std::shared_ptr` правильнее будет `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @alexolut Далеко не всегда. А если на объекты могут указывать из двух векторов? Честно говоря, `shared_ptr` в своей (да, небогатой) практике использовал многократно, даже когда-то свой собственный, когда в стандарте только `auto_ptr` был... а вот `unique_ptr`, честно говоря, даже не помню, использовал ли хоть раз.

Comment: `free` и `delete`, о которых упомянул ТС подразумевают окончательное удаление объекта. Т.е. вектор имеет объекты в эксклюзивном владении. Такое владение как раз реализует тип `unique_ptr`. `shared_ptr` тоже использовать можно для случая `use_count = 1`, то это лишний оверхед.

Comment: @alexolut Да, о том, что free/delete подразумевает окончательный расчет с объектом, я как-то не задумался... Сейчас подправлю ответ

Comment: @Harry Я правильно понял? Если мне надо удалить пару объектов, то использовать shared_ptr, а если вектор целиком, то unique_ptr?

Comment: @andrew Нет, имеется в виду, что если у вас указатели ТОЛЬКО в векторе, и вне вектора объект недоступен - то `unique_ptr`, а вот если, скажем, объект один, а указатели на него, скажем, есть в двух векторах - то `shared_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще вариант использовать

```
std::vector<Тип>().swap(Ваш_вектор);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш объект, содержащий вектор, отвечает за уничтожение хранящихся в нем объектов, то конечно, delete